# How to find unmatched rows in oracle without using set operator and join & also Query the unmatched column names for an particular row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on two tables test1 and test2 
I have to find the matched, unmatched, values in table test1 not in test2 ... vice versa

Then I have to do union of all the queries to get the final result.

But I'm having problem with unmatched part. With set operator I'm getting wrong result set when I compared it with excel sheet data then I'm getting 15 extra rows

**Note: there is no common column in both tables**

**Table:test1**

```
a     b        c
2001  abc    john
2008  cab    sam
2002  qwe    mike
2002  asd    samuel
2012  ddd    sammy
```

**Table:test2**

```
a      b      c
2001  abc    john
2008  c@b    saam
2009  qwe    mike
2002  asd    samuel
2001  a bc   john
```

**Output:**

unmatched rows from table test1 or test2 *here I'm assuming test2*

```
a        b      c      column_name
2008    c@b    saam      a,b
2009    qwe    mike    null
2001    a bc   john      b
```

I want the above output with the **unmatched rows** from the both table  and column_names.

**Column_names** contains the name of the columns which are unmatched in a particular row.

**My query (using minus )**

```
Select t2.a, t2.b, t2.c from
(Select a,b,c  from test1 t1
 Minus  
Select  a,b,c  from test2 t2)
```

**For column_name my logic was**:

```
Case when t1.a !=  t2.a then 'column a name' 
When t1.b 1= t2.b then 'column b name' 

 *....And so on .....*
```

But I think it can be done with the help of join that what I **don't want**

I am using Oracle 12c.

Comment: There's no (at least no kind of efficient) way to get your `column_name` logic.

Comment: This question caused me to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943385/oracle-bug-using-minus-and-union as union of the inverses minus  sets didn't result in what I expected.

Comment: The `column_name` concept makes no sense. If a row in table1 does not have a match in table2, that doesn't mean that there is one or more columns that doesn't (don't) have a match. Consider a simple example with two columns in each table. In the first one you have the row (1,'x'). In the second you have the rows (1, 'a') and (2, 'x'). Which column of the row (1, 'x') in table1 is unmatched? (Which row in table2 is the row in table1 "supposed" to match?)

Comment: @mathguy so is there any way to get the column names of that unmatched row in the result set

Comment: I just said the concept *makes no sense* and you are asking "so is there any way to get... in the result set"? Do you see the mismatch here? The concept **only** makes sense when both tables have a common PRIMARY KEY column (or combination of columns); then you match by primary key and you can see which columns are different, or which rows (which PK's) exist only in one table but not in both. If there is no specific way to identify rows between the tables, the whole "unmatched column" concept makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a union and minus twice.  Minus only looks at records in the first table not in second.  To see those not in both reverse the order of the tables when using minus then use a union.

```
With test1 (A,b,c) as (
SELECT 2001,  'abc',    'john' from dual union all
SELECT 2008,  'cab',    'sam' from dual union all
SELECT 2002,  'qwe',    'mike' from dual union all
SELECT 2002,  'asd',    'samuel' from dual union all
SELECT 2012,  'ddd',    'sammy' from dual),
test2 (a,b,c) as (
SELECT 2001, 'abc',    'john' from dual union all
SELECT 2008, 'c@b',    'saam' from dual union all
SELECT 2009, 'qwe',    'mike' from dual union all
SELECT 2002, 'asd',    'samuel' from dual union all
SELECT 2001, 'a bc',   'john' from dual )
-- ()'s matter here as UNION minus and select all occur at the same level of precedence.  
-- so test1-test2 union test2 minus test1 w/o them!
(Select * from test1 minus Select * from test2)
UNION ALL
(Select * from test2 minus Select * from test1)

--but if you use a cte it works...
With test1 (A,b,c) as (
SELECT 2001,  'abc',    'john' from dual union all--
SELECT 2008,  'cab',    'sam' from dual union all--x
SELECT 2002,  'qwe',    'mike' from dual union all--x
SELECT 2002,  'asd',    'samuel' from dual union all--
SELECT 2012,  'ddd',    'sammy' from dual),--x
test2 (a,b,c) as (
SELECT 2001, 'abc',    'john' from dual union all--
SELECT 2008, 'c@b',    'saam' from dual union all--x
SELECT 2009, 'qwe',    'mike' from dual union all--x
SELECT 2002, 'asd',    'samuel' from dual union all--
SELECT 2001, 'a bc',   'john' from dual ),
cte as (Select * from test1 minus Select * from test2),  --NEEDED
cte2 as (Select * from test2 minus Select * from test1)  --NEEDED
Select * from cte
union 
Select * from cte2;
```

Or this works too:

```
Select * from (
Select Distinct * from test1
UNION ALL
SELECT Distinct * From test2)
Group by A,B,C
having count(*) = 1
```

Using a full outer join we could get the column names... sort of.

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, case when coalesce(A.A,0)<>coalesce(B.A,-1) then 'A' end ||','||
                case when coalesce(A.B,'0')<>coalesce(B.B,'-0') then 'B' end ||','||
                case when coalesce(A.C,'0')<>coalesce(B.C,'-0') then 'C' end  as MisMatchOn
FROM test1 A
FULL OUTER JOIN Test2 B
on 1=1 
where length(case when coalesce(A.A,0)<>coalesce(B.A,-1) then 'A' end ||','||
                case when coalesce(A.B,'0')<>coalesce(B.B,'-0') then 'B' end ||','||
                case when coalesce(A.C,'0')<>coalesce(B.C,'-0') then 'C' end)<5
and replace(case when coalesce(A.A,0)<>coalesce(B.A,-1) then 'A' end ||','||
                case when coalesce(A.B,'0')<>coalesce(B.B,'-0') then 'B' end ||','||
                case when coalesce(A.C,'0')<>coalesce(B.C,'-0') then 'C' end,',','') is not null;
```

Comment: But is there any way i could get unmatched  column name also ?

Comment: I was playing with that.  Without doing a full outer join I can't see how to get the column names.  The reason is because all records have to be compared to all records which means we get a lot of non-matches we need to exclude.  I've added an example of a possible way but there's a fair amount of speculation in it