# Oracle minus and union order of operations/precedence

Tags: sql, oracle

I was assisting with:

[How to find unmatched rows in oracle without using set operator and join & also Query the unmatched column names for an particular row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942890/how-to-find-unmatched-rows-in-oracle-without-using-set-operator-and-join-also/45943039#45942890)

Consider the following trying to find all records found in one set but not the other. (note the --x below denotes records expected in result set)

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

```
With test1 (A,b,c) as (
SELECT 2001,  'abc',    'john' from dual union all--
SELECT 2008,  'cab',    'sam' from dual union all--x
SELECT 2002,  'qwe',    'mike' from dual union all--x
SELECT 2002,  'asd',    'samuel' from dual union all--
SELECT 2012,  'ddd',    'sammy' from dual),--x

test2 (a,b,c) as (
SELECT 2001, 'abc',    'john' from dual union all--
SELECT 2008, 'c@b',    'saam' from dual union all--x
SELECT 2009, 'qwe',    'mike' from dual union all--x
SELECT 2002, 'asd',    'samuel' from dual union all--
SELECT 2001, 'a bc',   'john' from dual ),--x

cte as (Select * from test1 minus Select * from test2),

cte2 as (Select * from test2 minus Select * from test1)

Select * from cte
union 
Select * from cte2;
```

which results in expected results:

```
+------+------+-------+
|  A   |    B |    C  |
+------+------+-------+
| 2001 | a bc | john  |
| 2002 | qwe  | mike  |
| 2008 | c@b  | saam  |
| 2008 | cab  | sam   |
| 2009 | qwe  | mike  |
| 2012 | ddd  | sammy |
+------+------+-------+
```

VS... (why do we need to use a CTE? can't we just union all the two queries?)

```
With test1 (A,b,c) as (
SELECT 2001,  'abc',    'john' from dual union all
SELECT 2008,  'cab',    'sam' from dual union all
SELECT 2002,  'qwe',    'mike' from dual union all
SELECT 2002,  'asd',    'samuel' from dual union all
SELECT 2012,  'ddd',    'sammy' from dual),

test2 (a,b,c) as (
SELECT 2001, 'abc',    'john' from dual union all
SELECT 2008, 'c@b',    'saam' from dual union all
SELECT 2009, 'qwe',    'mike' from dual union all
SELECT 2002, 'asd',    'samuel' from dual union all
SELECT 2001, 'a bc',   'john' from dual )

Select * from test1 minus select * from test2
union ALL
Select * from test2 minus select * from test1
```

Which just gives us.

```
+------+------+------+
|  A   |    B |    C |
+------+------+------+
| 2001 | a bc | john |
| 2008 | c@b  | saam |
| 2009 | qwe  | mike |
+------+------+------+
```

Apparently not... Why?  (comments indicate if I wrap each select in () for the minus it works (and it does) having to do with equal precedence in operation.)  So this works:

```
(Select * from test1 minus select * from test2)
union ALL
(Select * from test2 minus select * from test1)
```

I know I could union both sets after distinct and then do a having count... but why did the union of the inverse minused sets not work? Is it a bug (or a feature that I can't find doc on? :P)  [Answered in comments!] waiting for an answer to accept!

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT Distinct * FROM test1 UNION ALL
      SELECT Distinct * FROM test2)
GROUP BY A,B,C
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

So... what my query was doing was:

**[ANSWER FROM COMMENTS waiting for someone to post!]**

```
(Select * from test1 minus select * from test2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TEST2)
  MINUS select * from test1
```

instead of

```
(Select * from test1 minus select * from test2) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM TEST2 MINUS select * from test1)
```

Comment: Using parentheses around the queries *not using* cte's should give you the same result as with a cte.

Comment: True that does work; but doesn't that seem odd?  I would have thought the `union all` would be a sufficient separator.

Comment: all of the operators have equal precedence here..so they are evaluated from `left` to `right`.

Comment: Looks like I need to read up on operations and equal precedence. It works with the ()' I just  can't see why the version without ()'s doesn't work. it's like the compiler is ignoring a set of data or one of the statements even though a union all is occurring.  I would have expected set 1 to be generated set 2 to be generated and then those sets to be unioned.  Apparently not!  This is getting into a level of understanding for the compiler I wish I had !  Come on [Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1:0); explain this one! :P

Comment: `UNION` and `MINUS` have equal precedence, similar to how `+` and `-` operators do, and are evaluated left-to-right. E.g. `3 + 4 - 5 + 6` is not the same as `(3 + 4) - (5 + 6)`. For you, `a MINUS b UNION c MINUS d` is evaluated as `( (a MINUS b) UNION c) MINUS d`, which is not the same as `(a MINUS b) UNION (c MINUS d)`.

Comment: @andreas Got it.  That helped.  Vamsi had me on the right path I just didn't make the algebraic/mathematical relations; now I know!  the visual example was of great assistance; vamshi would get an upvote and you'd get the + for the visual aid.

Comment: @Andreas you should add that as an answer.

Comment: You don't have to use CTEs. They can be more efficient if you reuse them within the same query as Oracle will (may) materialise the set as an internal temp table.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson You're right I didn't/don't; but I didn't know why the results when I didn't use the CTE were wrong.  The ()'s matter since all the operations are at the same precedence.  Thus they are executed left to right giving me the wrong results w/o ()'s!

Comment: Ah, see what you mean now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select * from cte
union 
Select * from cte2
```

The `cte` s being `union`ed here evaluate `minus` operation on the 2 tables individually.

However, this query

```
Select * from test1 minus select * from test2
union ALL
Select * from test2 minus select * from test1
```

has `minus` and `union` which are set operators. All set operators have equal precedence. Hence they get evaluated one-by-one from `left` to `right`.

Hence the results of these queries are different. To explicitly specify the order, use parentheses around the two queries.

```
(Select * from test1 minus select * from test2)
union
(Select * from test2 minus select * from test1)
```

[Documentation on set operators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm#SQLRF52323)

Comment: Doc Link helped!

Comment: A very polite way of saying: RTFM! "All set operators have equal precedence. If a SQL statement contains multiple set operators, then Oracle Database evaluates them from the left to right unless parentheses explicitly specify another order."